# Mutually recursive functions - exercise not making sense to me

Tags: javascript

I know this is a silly way to determine even-odd numbers. It is just a lesson in recursion, and probably some other concepts as well.

The problem.

When I follow the logic, it looks like it doesn't matter what value you give "n", it will always eventually equal "0" and always end up "false".

What is going on?

```
function isOdd(x) {
    return !isEven(x);    
}

function isEven(x) {
    if(x===0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return isOdd(x-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code works as is: http://jsfiddle.net/BC9Pc/

Comment: it works for me. What problem did you face?

Comment: works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Kb9T5/1/  If you're sticking really large numbers into it, some browsers might crash on the deep recursion, but can't really see any other reason this wouldn't work.

Comment: Worth noting that this is an example of tail recursion, but unfortunately no Javscript engine (currently) optimizes for it.

Comment: Code is working. Now the only problem is that it seems x will always be chipped down to 0, whether its even or odd. Still trying to work that one out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### This is how isOdd returns true on an even number:

When you pass 2 to isOdd, it will forward this to isEven. Your call stack now looks like this (newest function is up):

```
isEven(2)
isOdd(2)
main
```

isEven will now call isOdd with 1:

```
isOdd(1)
isEven(2)
isOdd(2)
main
```

isOdd will again forward this to isEven:

```
isEven(1)
isOdd(1)
isEven(2)
isOdd(2)
main
```

the whole happens again with 0

```
isEven(0)
isOdd(0)
isEven(1)
isOdd(1)
isEven(2)
isOdd(2)
main
```

isEven now terminates with true, and the whole call-stack is rewinded. True is returned to isOdd:

```
isOdd(0)   <-true
isEven(1)
isOdd(1)
isEven(2)
isOdd(2)
main
```

isOdd will negate the return value, and thus return false to isEven:

```
isEven(1) <- false
isOdd(1)
isEven(2)
isOdd(2)
main
```

isEven again returns the result as-is to isOdd

```
isOdd(1) <- false
isEven(2)
isOdd(2)
main
```

isOdd negates and returns:

```
isEven(2) <- true
isOdd(2)
main
```

isEven returns as-is:

```
isOdd(2) <- true
main
```

isOdd negates and returns to main:

```
main <- false
```

### this is how isOdd returns false on an uneven number:

When isEven terminates, the call-stack looks like that.

```
isEven(0)
isOdd(0)
isEven(1)
isOdd(1)
main
```

isOdd receives true:

```
isOdd(0) <-true
isEven(1)
isOdd(1)
main
```

isOdd negates:

```
isEven(1) <- false
isOdd(1)
main
```

isEven returns the unchanged value:

```
isOdd(1) <- false
main
```

isOdd negates and returns to main:

```
main <- true
```

### So whats the explanation?

The whole trick is that when you have an odd number, there is an even number of negations in the call-stack. When you negate a boolean value an even number of times, it comes out as it was before. When you have an even number, you have an odd number of negations, and the result is changed.

Comment: Thanks! I was just about to draw all this out but probably wouldn't have done it as well. Didn't realize that there was a flip/flopping of true and false values as the stack bubbled up.

Answer (score 1):

> When I follow the logic, it looks like it doesn't matter what value
>   you give "n", it will always eventually equal "0" and always end up
>   "false".

you want to keep in mind how many isOdd are there in the stack trace. for instance: given x = 2

```
isOdd(2) => !isEven(2) => !(isOdd(1)) => !(!isEven(1)) => !(!(isOdd(0))) => !(!(!isEven(0))) => !(!(!(true)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works for me.  I tried it in Firefox and IE.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function isOdd(x) {
    return !isEven(x);    
}

function isEven(x) {
    if(x===0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return isOdd(x-1);
    }
}

alert(isOdd(6));

</script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive solutions have two requirements: a base case and an inductive step.  In this example, the base case is that `0` is even.  As it's the base case, it's expected and normal that all invocations eventually "chip down" to it.  The inductive step is that a number is even if it's one larger than an odd number.  But that's not a true induction step, because it defines evenness in terms of oddness.  So there's another rule required, that a number is odd if it's not even.  Showing rigorously that this terminates is a little tricky, but Phillipp's stack diagram is a decent demonstration of the fact.